# How to connect to FTP using ftp://userName@host

Tags: delphi, ftp

I'm having trouble connecting to the FTP sever. Most of the time I connect to an FTP server like this :

```
// ftp is TidFTP
ftp.Host := '119.xxx.xxx.133';
ftp.Username := 'fnc';
ftp.Password := 'fnc';
ftp.Port := 21;
ftp.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
ftp.Connect;
```

Our administrator gave me a link like this

```
ftp://fnc@119.xxx.xxx.133/Files/
```

to access the FTP. User name is *fnc*, port is 21, password is *fnc*.

If I access the FTP via Windows Explorer, I don't get any errors, I can put files flawlessly. But if I do it in code I get *illegal port command* errors whenever I try to put files.

Note that I can *connect* to the ftp server using the code above but can't *put any files* there.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your link doesn't have a password... `ftp://fnc:fnc@119.....`

Comment: ftp is TidFTP. @jery, if i use the link "ftp://fnc:fnc@119.xxx.xxx.133:21/Files/" it will work on windows explorer but will error in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an FTP URL, you need to parse the URL and assign its components to the various `TIdFTP` properties and methods, eg:

```
var
  URL: string;
  Uri: TIdURI;
begin
  ...
  URL := ...; // 'ftp://fnc:fnc@119.xxx.xxx.133/Files/'
  Uri := TIdURI.Create(URL);
  try
    ftp.Host := Uri.Host;
    if Uri.Port <> '' then
      ftp.Port := StrToInt(Uri.Port)
    else
      ftp.Port := 21;
    ftp.Username := Uri.Username;
    ftp.Password := Uri.Password;
    ftp.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
    ftp.Connect;
    if Uri.Path <> '/' then
      ftp.ChangeDir(Uri.Path);
    ...
  finally
    Uri.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ftp.passive := True
```

is the answer. Thansk to Sir Rufo.